# IHttpActionResult return Json object

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have created one method in `mvc api` which returns string. But instead of returning `string`, I want to return `Json Object`. Here is my code.

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("resetpassword")]
    public IHttpActionResult ResetPassword(string email)
    {
        CreateUserAppService();
        string newPassword =_userAppService.ResetPassword(email);

        string subject = "Reset password";
        string body = @"We have processed your request for password reset.<br/><br/>";
        string from = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[Common.Constants.FromEmailDisplayNameKey];
        body = string.Format(body, newPassword, from);

        SendEmail(email, subject, body, string.Empty);
        return Ok<string>(newPassword);
    }
```

Here it returns `Ok<string>(newPassword);` Now I want to return `Json object`. How can I return **Json object**?

Answer (score 13):

Try that:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
[Route("resetpassword")]
public IHttpActionResult ResetPassword(string email)
{
    //...
    return Json(newPassword);
}
```

Comment: It wasn't clear to me why I'd want to return a plain string, so I did something like `return Json(new {success = true});`

Answer (score 9):

You are actually already using the key thing...

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult Test()
{
     return Ok(new {Password = "1234"});
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to return it as CLR object so Web API serialize it to JSON, you can create your own POCO class or do it like this:

```
 var passResponse =  new
              {
                  newPassword= yourNewPassword
              };
```

But from security standpoint what you are doing is not correct, you should **NEVER** send plain passwords by email, you should reset user password by providing them a reset email link to your portal with some token and they should enter the new password. What you are doing here is not secure.

Comment: Hi Taiseer, Thank you for reply. I tried your code. It returns me "{ newPassword = FER3P74G }" But I want something like `{  "newPassword" :" FER3P74G" }`. How can I do this?

Comment: Try to create POCO class then

Comment: How can I create it? can you please post the code for it?

Comment: I tried `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(passResponse)` but it gives `"{\"email\":\"ajayp@sarvatranetwork.com\"}"` I don't want these `\`

Answer (score 1):

Create a return object.

```
public class PasswordResponse{
    public string Password {get;set;}
    //...other stuff to pass...
}
```

Then return an instance of the type in your response.

`return OK(new PasswordResponse(){Password = newPassword});`